# jQuery Mobile orientation change switch page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to display distinct pages in function of the orientation in JQuery Mobile.
I trigger the **orientationChange** event to call the **changePage** function.
The problem is that there is a period of time when the previous page stays and automatically adapt to the screen size before the next page displays.

I know some would say, why not adapt the css. But the two screens are really differents.
Any Idea?

Comment: something like splitview? one column in potrait mode and 2 in landscape mode?

Comment: I think it's a good alternative to what I was looking for. I didn't know this jquery mobile plugin. I will try it. Thanks @ghostCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/     splitview  plugin for jqm

Comment: Hey @GhostCoder please one more question, where should I change the min-width fo the splitview? Actually it splits at 768px. I tried to change it in the splitview css file but I failed. Workin' on a 7" tab screen

Comment: post as a separate question. difficult to answer in comments